# Solution to an ODE in the form $y'' + \frac{m}{mx+b} y' + k(mx + b)y = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I am trying to find a solution to a second order ODE in the form $y'' + \frac{m}{mx+b} y' + k(mx + b)y = 0$ where $m,a,b$ are constants. I cannot find a method to solve such form. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For large x this is the differential equation y''+k(mx+b)y=0 for the Airy functions, https://dlmf.nist.gov/9.2  which means y=c_1 Ai( (-mx-b)*(km)^(1/3)/m) + c2 Bi( (-mx-b)(k*m)^(1/3)/m). In general terms there is always a local solution by using the taylor series ansatz for the initial value problem, based on (mx+b)y''+my'+k(mx+b)^2y=0 .

Answer (score 1):

The point $x=-b/m$ is a singular point for this DE.  Near any other point $x \in \mathbb C$, this DE has an analytic solution.  And near $x=-b/m$ there are series solutions (described by Frobenius, and included in undergraduate ODE texts).  These series solutions possibly involve fractional powers of $(x+\frac{b}{m})$ or logarithms.

In this case, the solution is in terms of Bessel functions:
$$
y(x) =
C_{{1}}{{\rm J}_{0}\left({\frac {2}{3\,m}\sqrt {k} \left( mx+b
 \right) ^{{\frac{3}{2}}}}\right)}+C_{{2}}{{\rm Y}_{0}\left({\frac {2
}{3\,m}\sqrt {k} \left( mx+b \right) ^{{\frac{3}{2}}}}\right)}
$$
The $Y_0$ term behaves logarithmically near $-b/m$.